# Webbrowser control's PDF plugin configuration after Internet Explorer got retired

Tags: c#, winforms

PDF files are not getting displayed in my Winforms application, where WebBrowser controls is being used to display PDF files.
Earlier, we used to see if Internet Explorer is able to display the PDF files in the same system. If not, we used to make sure PDF plugin (Adobe or Foxit) is installed and loaded via Internet Explorer configuration section.
But now, since Internet Explorer has been retired, where to check for the settings?

Comment: Why not switch to WebView2?

Comment: As mentioned, the WebView2 Control (.NET Framework 4.5+), which *replaces* the old WebBrowser Control, can show PDF content, also from a file or in-lined (base64 content, limited to ~2MB size)

Comment: @Dai Very big application. Eventually, that is the plan.